# Delete a Library in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to delete a library from my project in Android Studio, but there's no delete option when I click on it. I also want to delete it from the project folder on disk.

How can I delete it?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press F4 (or File - Project Structure...), mark your module and click to remove icon:

[image]